# Using Robolectric to test HTTPS connections

Tags: android, https, robolectric

My project uses HTTPS:

```
URL url = new URL("https://blah.com");
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
...
```

Is it possible to test this with Robolectric?  FakeHttpLayer doesn't seem to work with HTTPS, as far as I can see:

```
FakeHttpLayer fakeHttpLayer = new FakeHttpLayer();
fakeHttpLayer.setDefaultHttpResponse(200, "All ok");
```

has no effect on my app, which hits a `java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect`.

(Naturally I would need to sort out the certificates so that my app trusted the shadow.)

Comment: Mark, can you give detail what exactly you're trying to test? That you pass correct url? That is you process correct response? That url is passed correctly to HttpsURLConnection?

Comment: The essential part is to allow my app to think it has successfully made the post.  The URL I'm connecting to isn't available to the build machine so it needs to be simulated. Getting a hard-coded 200 response back would get me started and from there I can add more thorough testing such as URL correctness etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you comment correctly then my advice will be next:

- Create an class `Network` (name it properly as you think)
- Inject it in the places where you want to do networking
- Mock it in the test and check that you call it correctly